# PL/SQL ORA06550 error in an update statement

Tags: sql, syntax

The following is a proc code that I have written . I am getting a syntax error in the block marked from (A) to (B) , namely , `ORA06550`, saying SQL command not ended properly.

If I eliminate the line `l.ban4_upd ='UPDATED'` there are no more of nay error messages.
I don't know how to correct it . Hoping for your help and thanks in advance

```
DECLARE
    dummy_BAN4 VARCHAR2(30);
    dummy_bank_acc_num VARCHAR2(20);

    CURSOR c_customers is
       SELECT BAN4,Bank_acc_num FROM Test_Table ;

BEGIN
   OPEN c_customers;
   LOOP
      FETCH c_customers into dummy_BAN4 , dummy_bank_acc_num;
      IF c_customers%notfound THEN
      update Test_Table chs Set
      chs.error_msg ='No such record found in  DB '
      where bank_acc_num =dummy_bank_acc_num; 
        END IF;

    update Transact_ord2 l Set.........................(A)
    l.ban4_upd ='UPDATED'
    l.x_account_number =dummy_BAN4
    where X_account_number =dummy_bank_acc_num;   ..........(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `,` between the fields you set:

```
update Transact_ord2 
Set ban4_upd = 'UPDATED',
x_account_number = dummy_BAN4
where X_account_number = dummy_bank_acc_num;
```

[Check this](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/update)

Comment: In a part following this I have written a similar update statement but no errors for that : 
update  Transact_profile@dblink2mondb p Set
     P.CUST_BANK_ACC_NUM =dummy_IBAN
      where CUST_BANK_ACC_NUM =dummy_bank_acc_num;   
  END LOOP;
   CLOSE c_customers; 
  END;

Comment: @privateryan - you are not getting the error yet because it fails to compile before that

Comment: Haven't yet checked ...will let you know soon . Could you tell me as to why do you think it fails to compile before that ?

Comment: Frm my experience in PL/SQL developer when it has a compile error then it gives them one by one. In any case for this update statement I'd recommend to execute it separately to check if it is valid. This way you have less things influencing your testing.

Comment: Will check and let you know soon ...Thanks a lot